# What is the formal code review process of the standard client?

Tags: bitcoin-core

There are n developers with commit privileged.

After one of them merges a pull request, how many eyes review that code? When? Is a complete (holistic) code review done before releasing a version? Does every line gets reviewed by at least one other person?

Comment: Support documents: http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Release_process
 http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Development_process

Answer (score 2):

According to the bitcoin.it wiki, as Stephen Gornick linked to in a comment, this should be the code review process:

> Pull requests are discussed on the forums and if there is consensus they're safe, tested, useful, well written, match coding style, etc. then they're merged into the 'master' branch.

Assuming the bitcointalk.org forums, I can't really find any pull request discussion. On Github it seems pull requests do get discussed though, for example: [Bloom filter pull request](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/1795).